# android. why time picker is not symmetric?

Tags: android, timepicker

I use TimePicker. And I noticed that it is not symmetric. Sign ":" Located right of center.

i use `timepicker.setIs24HourView(true);`

unfortunately I did not show a screenshot, because my reputation is below 10

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/LSaoL-hWitPVX - link to a screenshot

Comment: can someone check on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

The `TimePicker` should be symmetric, probably you have some paddings in its parent view or some margins in the `TimePicker`.

Comment: unfortunately no. i have set padding and margin = 0dp, but it hasn't given result